# Draw TIN using Delaunay triangulation and find surface area

Tags: networking, network-programming, delaunay

I have set of `x,y,z` values and I want to draw a triangulated irregular network (TIN) using Delaunay triangulation.

I'd like to start from basic things and also I want to calculate the surface area of the TIN.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about C++? Then you could use [Fade2.5D](https://www.geom.at/fade25d/html/). Reading the points, triangulating, visualizing and area calculation needs only a few lines:

```
#include <Fade_2D.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace GEOM_FADE25D;


int main()
{
    // Read points from x y z-file
    vector<Point2> vInputPoints;
    readXYZ("yourFileName.xyz",vInputPoints);

    // Triangulate
    Fade_2D dt;
    dt.insert(vInputPoints);

    // Show
    dt.show("triangulation.ps"); // Postscript, 2D view
    dt.showGeomview("triangulation.list"); // Geomview-scene, 2.5D
    
    // Compute the area
    vector<Triangle2*> vTriangles;
    dt.getTrianglePointers(vTriangles);
    double sumArea(0);
    for(Triangle2* pT:vTriangles)
    {
            sumArea+=pT->getArea25D();
    }
    std::cout<<"Number of triangles: "<<vTriangles.size()<<", area="<<sumArea<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Fade's student license is free (I'm the author).